# Quickest way to select an entire Sass ruleset in Vim?

Tags: vim, sass

Just starting with Vim and I wondered – given a Sass block like this:

```
.thing {
    width: 100%;
    color: $color1;
    .nested {
        height: 1rem;
    }
}
```

If my cursor is at the 'd' within 'width', what's the quickest way to visually select the entire rule set, selector, braces and all?

At present I am using 'Shift+}' to jump to the next blank line and then 'v' for visual and 'Shift+{' to select the prior block. Any better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close. As you're already using the `{` and `}` motions to the borders of the current paragraph, just use the related *text object*: `Vip`, where `V` starts (linewise, but you can also use `v` as this text object forces this) visual mode, and `ip` selects the *inner paragraph*.

Comment: @BenFrain despite you asked about visually selecting the block, you could also directly apply your action to the text object - for deleting, `dip`; copying, `yip`; etc.