# Quickest way to select a nested Sass block with Vim?

Tags: vim, sass

Back in this post: [Quickest way to select an entire Sass ruleset in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636276/quickest-way-to-select-an-entire-sass-ruleset-in-vim) I got a great shortcut to select an entire rule in Sass with Vim.

However, I wondered if there is a quick way to select a nested rule. So, if the cursor is somewhere within the nested rule below (let's say the 'h' of height):

```
.thing {
    width: 100%;
    color: $color1;
    .nested {
        height: 1rem;
    }
}
```

What's the quickest way I can select just that nested rule in Vim? To be clear, I want to select:

```
.nested {
    height: 1rem;
}
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I tried `vaBV` and it worked fine, what is happening when you try it?

Comment: Apologies, error between keyboard and chair ;) – I was starting with my cursor in the `@include` part instead of inside. In that case the `vaBV` selects the outer (and I now understand why given your extended answer below) set of braces. Thanks for this. Makes total sense now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty close to the question you linked to. Just move the pointer anywhere within the `{}` block, and select the `{}` block with `vaB`, and then switch to linewise with `V`

So all together it's just `vaBV`

Or, if you have your cursor on any part of `.nested {` you can just do `V%`

I only really use either though if it's faster than `Vjj` or `V2j` or whatever

Comment: That's great AndreZS, thanks. Couple related questions. I understood that B was backwards Word – is this different in Visual mode (or does the definition of a word simply differ in the context of Sass/CSS)? Also, it's worth readers knowing that nested mixins don't work this way. I'll update the original question with an example of what I mean.

Comment: When you are in visual mode you get extra selector commands `a` and `i`. (see [*motion.txt*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) section 6). You use these to select text objects, such as text from `(` to `)` by typing `va)` or `va(`. `a` stands for "outer", and includes the braces, while `i` stands for "inner" and excludes them. Vim gives you shortcuts like `b` for either of `(` or `)`, and in this particular example, `B` for curly braces `{}`. Pressing `V` at the end sends you to a line-wise selection.